# How do I make my div stay on the right side?

Tags: html, css

Currently my website has a header and a left sidebar. I now want to make a div to place a lot of text inside of it, however when I tried to, instead of staying to the right it stays under the sidebar. I tried adding the float property to the sidebar but it doesn't work.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="box">
      <div id="header">
        <i
          ><img
            class="oldenhook_icon"
            src="icons/icon2.png"
            alt="The Oldenhook Icon"
        /></i>
        <div>
          <h1 class="header_h1">[&nbsp;oldenhook&nbsp;]</h1>
          <ul class="flexbox">
            <a href="#" class="list-item">home</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">search</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">global</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">social net</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">invite</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">faq</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">logout</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="searchbox">
            
           <label class="label" for="email">E-mail:</label>
           <input name="email" id="email" type="text">
           <br>
           <label class="label" for="pass">Password:</label>
           <input name="pass" id="password" type="password">
           <button class="button">Login</button>
           <button class="button">Register</button>
           
      </div>
      <div id="container_head"></div>
    </div>
```

Here's the CSS stylesheet:

```
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

:root {
  --color-primary: #b22222;
  --color-secondary: #800000;
  --color-white: #d9dfea;
}

/* Box */

#box {
  margin: 2% 20%;
}

/* Header */

#header {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.oldenhook_icon {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.header_h1 {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  font-family: "Noto Sans Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* float: right; */
  position: relative;
  left: 26%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 22%;
}

.list-item {
  color: var(--color-white);
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Search box */

#searchbox {
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#email {
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #bdc7d8;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 95px;
}

#password {
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #bdc7d8;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  width: 95px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.button {
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  color: var(--color-white);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: var(--color-white);
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Container */

#container_head {
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your time and learn about **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)**. It makes positioning much more easier.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just fixed it by wrapping the two divs with nav and using the display as flexbox row. I will for sure master flexbox, cheers.